# How to unplug a MacBook power connector (MagSafe) safely?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, adapter, magsafe

I just started to use a MacBook and the device uses a MagSafe magnetic adapter connector.

However, it is almost impossible to remove the magnetic connector from device "without damaging it".

I tried to find a proper way on YouTube but unfortunately there is no info for that. I also unplug the adapter first, but it does not make any sense.

So, how can I unplug MacBook Pro magnetic adapter properly without giving damage?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't damage it to just pull it away; it's designed to be safe even if someone snags the cable - so the plug will come away without the laptop being dragged onto the floor.

If just pulling makes you feel uncomfortable for some reason, just tilt it upwards or downwards first, which will break away half the magnetic force, making the pull easier.

Comment: You right, I also seen that when I searched on the web. But for my situation it is impossible to unplug it even a big car sticks around its cable. On the other hand, I also thought tilting upwards or downwards, but it may give damage until a certain period of time and I thought there must be a normal way. Any idea?

Comment: The 'normal way' is just pull it. Apple sells about 20 million or more of these a year. If it was an issue, you can be sure there would have been an outcry about it before now.

Comment: That's why I thought that I did something wrong. But as a technical guy, it was also less likely :)